# Como trabalhar com variáveis de ambiente?

Tags: java, sistema-operacional

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que trabalha com arquivos (salvar e carregar) e tenho que trabalhar com variáveis do sistema para determinar onde salvar esses arquivos.

A minha dúvida é: Existe alguma forma de utilizar variáveis independente do sistema operacional? Se sim, como devo proceder. Por exemplo, eu sei que se eu colocar uma variável `caminho`, por exemplo no windows da seguinte forma:

```
%caminho%\algum_dir\algum_arquivo.exemplo
```

Ele converterá `%caminho%` para a string contida nessa variável. O mesmo vale para Linux, só que utilizando `$caminho`. Então, em resumo, queria saber se é possível usar algum tipo de nomenclatura para o programa detectar uma variável do ambiente, que tenha um nome definido por mim, independente do SO, já que o programa será em Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer é o método [`getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()). Ele é responsável por ler as variáveis de ambiente e cuida das especificidades dos sistemas operacionais. Retirei este código do [tutorial oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html):

```
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QsjD0Z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rcyurmtg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/Environment.java).

Eu imagino que você consiga pegar o que deseja a partir daí. Documentação do [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Essencialmente a chave é a variável e o valor é o conteúdo dela.